# Sharp upper bound for $E(h(Y))$ where $Y \sim N(0, 4)$ with constraint that $E(h(Z)) = 0$ where $Z$ is standard normal

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

The question comes from [Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a core course](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387938387) Ch. 12 Question 2

The exact wording is: "Suppose $sup|h(x)| = M$ and $Eh(Z) = 0$, where $Z \sim N(0,1)$. Give a sharp upper bound for $Eh(2Z)$."

This is the solution in the back of the book, [image: solution]

I don't understand how $k'$ was determined, and also I'm struggling to understand how that connects to evaluating $Eh^*(2Z)$.

Any hints would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to addd that, $sup|h(x)| = M$

Comment: That's crucial, for otherwise there is no maximum.  Please edit your post to include this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the CDF gynmastics below:

The logic says $h(x)=\pm M$ depending on whether the likelihood ratio is bigger or smaller than the optimal multiplier $k'$. This means that the constraint equation can be written as:

\begin{align*}
0=\int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)f_0(x)dx &= -M [\Phi(k')-\Phi(-k')]+M[\Phi(-k')+1-\Phi(k')]\\
&=M+2M\Phi(-k')-2M\Phi(k')\\
&=M(1+2(1-2\Phi(k'))
\end{align*}

or, $1+2-4\Phi(-k')=0$, giving $k'=\Phi^{-1}(3/4)$.